# JSON output contains asterisks instead of values

Tags: java, json, jackson, osgi

When I use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload)` to get a `json` string from an object I am finding some fields have asterisks instead of values. Like this:

```
{
    "id": "25495867-1404-412d-9488-ce495bd468de",
    "createdDate": "2019-09-01T22:27:46.000Z",
    "updatedDate": "2019-09-01T22:27:46.000Z",
    "externalKey": "testhc1",
    "email": **********************,
    "name": ************,
    "currency": "NZD"
}
```

Both `email` and `name` have values in my payload object, and I cannot see anything odd about the fields. But clearly the `jackson` code does. Not only are the values obscured but the resulting asterisks aren't in quotes so they aren't valid `json` for the other end of this process to parse successfully.

Does anyone know what triggers this behaviour? I've spent the day looking at the code and not found anything. The payload object is not annotated but I've tried other unannotated objects that work fine.

---

Edit 1029/09/03
The code I'm writing is a plugin for [Killbill](http://killbill.io/) and it seems to behave differently when running outside that environment. I wrote a small test:

```java
UUID accountId = UUID.fromString("25495867-1404-412d-9488-ce495bd468de");
DefaultAccount account = new DefaultAccount(
        accountId, "external", "abc@gmail.com",
        "fred smith", 4, Currency.NZD, null, false, 
        20, null, new DateTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC,
        Locale.getDefault().toString(), "addr1", 
        "addr2", "companyName", "city",
        "stateOrProvince", "country", 
        "postalCode", "phone", "notes", false);
try {
    String json = invoiceNotificationHttpClient.getMapper().writeValueAsString(account);
    logger.info("testMapper: {} " ,json);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
}
```

The result of running the test directly (ie outside KillBill) gives me the result I expect, ie

```
{
    "id": "25495867-1404-412d-9488-ce495bd468de",
    "externalKey": "external",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "name": "fred smith",
    "firstNameLength": 4,
    "currency": "NZD",
...
}
```

I took this exact code and pasted it into my plugin. You can see I'm just instantiating a class and running the mapper on it. When running as a plugin the result is this:

```
{
    "id": "25495867-1404-412d-9488-ce495bd468de",
    "externalKey": "external",
    "email": ***************,
    "name": ************,
    "firstNameLength": 4,
    "currency": "NZD",
...
}
```

There are my asterisks. So it isn't the class itself, it looks like it might be the mapper. So I took a look at that.

The mapper does come from the framework, but I have the source of that. I extend the given class `org.killbill.billing.plugin.util.http.HttpClient` to produce my `InvoiceNotificationHttpClient`. So in my class there's a method:

```java
    protected ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        return super
                .createObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(new JodaModule())
                .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    }
```

This is calling the superclass and adding what I need for Joda. In the superclass:

```java
    protected ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Tells the serializer to only include those parameters that are not null
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

        // Allow special characters
        mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS, true);

        // Write dates using a ISO-8601 compliant notation
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

        return mapper;
    }
```

and that looks happy enough to me. It should be the same as I have when running standalone anyway.

---

edit 2019-09-03 again

I'm starting to think I must be getting a different ObjectMapper when I run as a plugin. I moved the above instantiation and configuration of ObjectMapper into its own method in the plugin and tried that as a test. The same technique still works just fine standalone, and doesn't work in the plugin. So `new ObjectMapper()` seems to be giving me something different in those environments. This is probably an OSGi question now. I'll update the tags.

Comment: What is the Java type of the `name` and `email` fields? Are they `String`s or something else? It would be useful to include the source code for the object that contains those fields in your question.

Comment: Could you use step-by-step debugging? Looks like this would be the easiest way to identify the culprit

Comment: `Jackson` does not generate wrong `JSON` by default for any `POJO`. It will serialise object to valid `JSON` or throw exception if it is not possible. Do you have any custom configuration like a custom serialisers?

Comment: @JonK Both the examples I gave are String fields, but I've seen an Integer field (not an int) do it on another object. The object is just a POJO, though with no setters and big constructor methods instead, and all the getters are there.

Comment: @MichałZiober I'm getting my ObjectMapper created by some third party code, but I've looked at where they generate it and they aren't doing anything weird. When I produce an ObjectMapper the same way it seems okay, though I do add the Joda date handling to mine. These fields aren't dates though.

Comment: @Aaron I could, but there's a lot of code and a lot of fields and I'm hoping this is a known behaviour. It looks it ought to be.

Comment: @RogerParkinson, if `ObjectMapper` created by 3rd party code generates stars and if you create manually `ObjectMapper` and it works properly it means that 3rd party code does some tricks. It would be great if you could create an example which reproduces this error. It would be much easier for us to find problem and help you. Is this 3rd party code is public library or framework?

Comment: @MichałZiober I appreciate the help. I've added more to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This was a complete red herring but I'll post the answer in case it helps someone else. The asterisks were not caused by anything odd in the jackson `ObjectMapper`. Nor were they caused by any strange classpath issues in the OSGi configuration. I spent ages looking for those problems and found nothing.

What they were caused by is a `conversionRule` in the `logback` configuration designed to mask those specific fields from turning up in logs. This is a reasonable requirement, but I was not aware the server I was embedding my OSGi plugin was doing that. It turns out, when I turn off that conversion, the fields are just fine. When I ran my desktop tests they had a simpler `logback` configuration that did not include the `conversionRule` so it never showed up there.